# API call with Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, authorization, httprequest, basic-authentication

im currently trying to call on a API using "GET" method in javascipt, but i don't seem to get any access. This is the code.

```
loadLibrary("cus:json3.js"); 

try {

var buffer = new MemoryBuffer();
buffer.fromString("username" + ':' + "password", "utf-8");

var http = new HttpClientRequest();
http.header["Authorization"] = "Basic " + buffer.toBase64();
this.baseURL = "https://url...";
http.url = this.baseURL;

http.method = "GET";
http.execute();

logInfo();

var response = http.response;

  }


} catch(e) {
logInfo(e);
}
```

But all i get is -55 error. Not sure why I can't access the API like this. Does anybody have an idea that would be awsome. The firewall has allowed the IP that my program is using.

Comment: Are you able to confirm that your Authorization header is the same as it is in an environment where your request *does* work?

Comment: Yes, from word of mouth, no other confirmation.